# Why i can't write char to binary file in C programming?

Tags: c, binary, char, binaryfiles

```
int main(){

    FILE *fptr=fopen("clients.dat","wb");
    char a='c';
    //int b=5;
    fwrite(&a,sizeof(char),1,fptr);
}
```

Why when i run this program "clients.dat" is not binary file.But if i comment char and uncomment int then clients.dat file is binary file.It is the same in struct. If there is only char inside struct then it doesn't create binary file,but if there is char and other data type then it creates binary file.

Can anyone write the reason of this?

Comment: Is that your code? The html `<br>` suggests you copied it. Please show a dump of the output file.

Comment: Yes. Actually i did it ,because when i write it without <br> it shows code messy

Comment: Why have you destroyed my formatting correction? Rolled back to the code you posted.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "binary" or "text" file. Files are files, bytes are bytes. It is how one chooses to *interpret* those bytes that makes a file a certain type. In C, when you open a file in "b" mode, that means whatever bytes you write will go the the file as is: if you write a 'c', it will get a 'c'. In text mode, the library may add or change some bytes, particularly things like line endings, to conform the system's idea of what "text" is, but the file itself is still just bytes.

Comment: The program (presumably a text editor) that you're opening the file in sees the `'c'` character as the only byte appearing in the file, sees that this byte represents the `c` character in your platform's default character set, and reaches the rightful conclusion that the file is actually a text file. When writing `int a = 5`, none of the bytes that make up the `int` represent a valid character in your platform's character set, thus leading the program to tell you that the file is "binary".

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker : This is just spot on. I really wish more programmers understood the difference exactly this way.

Comment: i didn't get it .Does it mean i can't write character or an array of characters to binary file?

Answer (score 2):

You're writing to an existing file which was opened with mode "wb", **[which will overwrite the existing contents of the file](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/)**. So, your single character `'c'` is written to the beginning of the file, and regardless of whatever was in there before, it's now the only thing in your file.

As for why it's no longer being considered binary, that's because `'c'` is a printable character.

Comment: it is still the same if i change mode to ab or rb+ . But i need to write this character to binary file

Comment: @mirzemehdi All files are binary; that is, a sequence of bytes.  If all the bytes in a file represent printable or whitespace characters, many programs will treat that file as a "text file".  Your file contains only one byte, and it has the same value as a printable character, so those programs will claim or presume it to be text.  But if any program wants to treat it as a binary file and just read that byte, it still can, and will get the value you put in.